# How to force onDestroy method of the Service

Tags: android, android-service

Is there a way to force onDestroy method of the Service from the Android OS or, say, explicitly?

Ok, I think I found a way how to do it manually.
I think that if you declare a service as a remote(Only for debugging purposes, because remote service is not a best app design case):

```
    <service android:name="widget.SomeWidget"
        android:process=":remote" />
```

And then in the DDMS Devices overview you can just stop the remote service.
I believe it has the same affect as killing the process by the Android OS.

Result from LogCat:

```
INFO/ActivityManager(38): Process asd.asd.asd:remote (pid 4104) has died.
INFO/ActivityManager(38): Start proc asd.asd.asd:remote for service asd.asd.asd/widget.SomeWidget: pid=4230 uid=10028 gids={3003, 1015}
```

Comment: Yes, the best case is to make the OS to stop this service

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The OS killing the service is not controlled by you. The best you can do is call Context.stopService()
The closest workaround would be to try something like this:

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("kill "+processId);
```

Where processId is the PID of the process you want to kill. 
You will need a rooted phone for this.

Answer (score 1):

No it makes more sense to call `yourOwnDestroy()` method which handles the clean up tasks, through the service binder interface; relying on `onDestroy()` to be called is not recommended.

`onDestroy()` will be scheduled to be called some time after `unbindService()` and `stopService()`

Answer (score 0):

Call Context.stopService() to stop the service, or stopSelf() from inside the service.

Comment: that is how you stop the service, but I need to simulate the OS to kill the service(and then it supposed to be onDestroy method to be called)

Comment: Why exactly do you need to do this?  Are you doing it for testing?

Comment: Yes, only for the testing purposes

Comment: Take a look at ServiceTestCase.  If you write a unit test for your service, you can do what you want -- onDestroy is public so you can conceivably call it from within your test case.